# Magento ver. 1.9.3.7 not saving info when updated in Admin. It says: "The configuration has been saved." but does NOT save it

Tags: magento-1.9, database, system-config

```
Magento ver. 1.9.3.7
Porto theme
```

I did a fresh install of Magento ver. 1.9.3.7. I installed the Porto theme on top of it. Everything has been working great (I changed some settings around in the Admin panel and saved them and it used to save).

The only thing I've done since then was to add a Domain Alias in the cPanel of the main domain in order to add a 2nd website/store and add the following instruction into the .htaccess file:

```
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks

  SetEnvIf Host .*MYNEWSTORE.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=MYNEWSTORE
  SetEnvIf Host .*MYNEWSTORE.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website  

    RewriteEngine on
```

Now, when I go to the Admin and change anything and then SAVE it (by clicking on Save Config) - it says:

*The configuration has been saved.*

But it N**EVER saves anything!** It just reverts back to what it was before I tried to change it!

---

UPDATED - now that I've tried and put the ORIGINAL .htaccess back - **it works again!** (saves my updates in the Admin panel). **WHY IS THAT?** I took the same code from the .htaccess file I have running on a Magento 1.9.1 install and it works there great! **How else do I suppose to setup another domain/website on the same install?**

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I uploaded the .htaccess from the Magento 1.9.1 instead.

It started working when I uploaded the correct .htaccess file.